# Filtering Many-to-Many-to-Many

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, multiple-values, connection-filters

**What I Need:**

I'm trying to use OOTB features, with as little custom rendering / SPFx / customization as possible.

I've got 3 list: Members, Classes and Sponsors.
Each Member may be in many classes, each class may have many sponsors.

I want to provide the end user with a method of viewing all members whose class was sponsored by a given sponsor.

For Example: I want to view all members whose class was sponsored by Microsoft.

My lists are setup as follows:

```
Members - Multi-Value lookup column to Classes (called Class Name)
Classes - Multi-Value lookup column to Sponsors. (called Sponsors)
```

**What I have tried**

I've tried using the OOTB SharePoint list filter and it seems to have the capability to do what I want. However, I can't seem to get the "Value Field" and "Description Fields" to work. I select the filter list to use classes with a Value field of `Class Name` and a Description Field of `Sponsors`. But when the filter popup opens, I see a concatenation of the two fields, instead of just the `Sponsors` Field.

Is there any way I can achieve what I am looking for?